# Удаленный доступ на Windows 10 с Kali linux?

Tags: linux, kali-linux

Хочу получить удаленный доступ своего рабочего ПК на windows, из kali linux.

Comment: https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?46345-Enabling-Remote-Desktop-and-SSH-access-to-Kali )

Comment: xfreerdp вам нужен

Comment: Remmina .......

Comment: Удалённый доступ бывает разный, уточните что именно вы хотите

Answer (score 1):

1. На линуксе обязательно должен быть установлен samba-клиент.
2. В винде обязательна поднята служба "сервер"
   Это для доступа в файловую систему виндоуз-машины
   Дополнительно:
   [Настройка файлового обмена между Windows и Ubuntu.](https://linuxrussia.com/share-files-between-ubuntu-and-windows.html)
   [Получаем доступ к папкам и файлам windows 10 по сети](https://chuzhoy007.ru/poluchaem-dostup-k-papkam-i-fajlam-windows-10-po-seti)

Answer (score 0):

Если имеется ввиду классическое представление об удаленном доступе то любой RDP клиент под Linux (в случает если машина с виндой находится в той же сети что и kali, без проброса портов и доступа из паблик сети), например как советовали выше Remmina. Более удобный вариант как по мне - это развернуть на винде VNC сервер, в этом случае получить доступ к винде можно будет из клиентов под любую ос использую учетную запись vnc.